# Variable returning as undefined in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, variables, undefined

I am getting the following error message for each variable:

`Message: Undefined index:` on lines 59, 60, 61, 62

I cannot understand why as it is definitely getting the sessions data and also the databases are setup and their is a user which matches that criteria.

jobs.php(apply function):

```
public function apply(){

if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')){
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('job');

        $id = $this->session->userdata('id');

        $query = $this->db->get_where('jobseeker_profiles', array('jobseeker_id' => $id));
        $user = $query->row_array();

        $points = $user['total_points_value'];
        $name = $user['name'];
        $email = $user['email'];
        $jobseeker_profile_id = $user['id'];
        $employer_profile_id = $this->input->post('employer_id');
        $job_id = $this->input->post('job_id');

        $this->db->set('jobseeker_profile_id', $jobseeker_profile_id);
        $this->db->set('employer_profile_id', $employer_profile_id);
        $this->db->set('job_id', $job_id);
        $this->db->set('name', $name);
        $this->db->set('email', $email);
        $this->db->set('points_value', $points);

        if($this->input->post('submit')){
            $this->db->insert('applications');
        }

        redirect('applied-for');

    }else{
        redirect('login');
    }
}
}
```

Hope fully you can help, thanks!

Comment: What is on line numbers 59, 60, 61, 62?

Comment: A simple Google search would give you the answer

Comment: @AmalMurali Sorry, it is the four variables $points, $name, $email and $jobseeker_profile_id

Comment: @Mike I have been searching on the web but can't find what I'm looking for, if you have any suggestions on a solution that would be great?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: @Mike in what way is that a duplicate, totally different problem!!!!

Comment: @AyeTry it means the array `$user` doesn't have an index called `total_points_value`, or any of the others on the other lines.

Comment: @Mike I'm aware that's what it means, I asked if you had a solution?

Comment: It means that `$user = $query->row_array();` is not adding those indexes to $user. Try doing `var_dump($user)`

Comment: @Mike array(0) { } it displays this

Comment: So then you will have to figure out what's going on with `$query->row_array()`. Maybe there are `0` rows that match, and that's why it is returning an empty array

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if the 4 database variables you are setting in those lines are rightly declared in the table ? They have to match to work.

Answer (score 0):

do some quick error checking directly from the controller or model like

```
 // check if query did not come back
 if ( ! $query = $this->db->get_where('jobseeker_profiles',array('jobseeker_id' => $id)) ) 
{ echo 'OMFG WHERE IS MY QUERY ???' ; } 
else
{   $user = $query->row_array(); 

    echo 'QUERY WORKED, User Name is:' . $user['name'] ;
}
```

and if this does not work, go back and make sure you are loading the database, that the user/password is correct, etc